# Getting count groupby right on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
    code
0   0000
1   0000  
2   0123  
3   0123
4   4567
```

I want to groupby code and count how many of each code there is in the dataframe, so it get to look like this:

```
   code  count     
0  0000      2 
1  0123      2
2  4567      1
```

I was using: group=df.groupby('code').agg('count')
However I wasn't getting it right.

Can someone help?

Comment: `df.groupby('code').size()`

Comment: Or, `df.code.value_counts()`

Comment: thanks, that was it

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and I'm forming @user3483203's comments into an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Using:

```
df.groupby('code').size()

# OR

df.code.value_counts()
```

This groups all rows with matching codes and outputs the total for each code.